# Why can I still ping the host if the Docker network is set to internal?

Tags: docker, networking, routes, ping

Docker docs about "Network internal mode":

> By default, when you connect a container to an `overlay` network, Docker also connects a bridge network to it to provide external connectivity. If you want to create an externally isolated `overlay` network, you can specify the `--internal` option.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#network-internal-mode

However, while I cannot reach the internet or other services on the host network when using a network with the `--internal` option - I noticed that I can still ping the Docker host from inside the container.

Minimal example:

```
# create example network with `--internal` option
docker network create --internal internal
# ping Docker host from inside container
docker run -it --rm --network=internal debian:buster sh -c "ping $(hostname -I | sed -r -e 's/^.*(192[^ ]*).*$/\1/')"
```

Comment: Do you get the same result creating your network with `docker network create -d overlay --internal internal` ? You above command created a typical bridge network on my single node and I don't have a swarm to test this one.

Comment: My other question would be whether that `ping` invocation is actually reaching the host, or whether it's looking up the container's Docker-internal IP address and sending ICMP packets to itself.

Comment: Well I have to admit the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) is not really clear on this point. It states that the `--internal` option can be used for all drivers but the details are only talking about the overlay driver. From my latest test, it works for basic bridge (delta your current question). Sorry if I introduced any confusion.

Comment: Right: "docker run -it --rm --network=internal debian:buster sh -c "ping google.com"" => can't resolve hostname. `docker run -it --rm --network=internal debian:buster sh -c "ping 216.58.213.174"` => hangs, 100% packet lost. But your current question remains (I can ping the docker host).